# What is a monoidal groupoid?

Tags: category-theory

I have heard the term **monoidal groupoid** mentioned, and I'm trying to understand what it means.

I understand what a [group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)) is, and that a monoid is similar to a group except that each element need not have an inverse. Also, it seems that a [groupoid](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/groupoid) is like a group where different elements may act on different (isomorphic) underlying objects.

Combining these definitions, it seems as if a monoidal groupoid should be a set of (potentially non-invertible) morphisms between isomorphic objects. So it is essentially a category, but with the additional restriction that the objects of the category be isomorphic. Is this correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.  "Monoidal groupoid" is a combination of "groupoid" with "monoidal category", not "monoid".  So a monoidal groupoid is a groupoid (category in which every morphism is invertible) which is also equipped with the structure of a [monoidal category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidal+category).

Note also that not all objects in a groupoid need to be isomorphic.  All the morphisms are isomorphisms, but some pairs of objects might have no morphisms between them at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think I'm still missing something. Isn't a groupoid already a monoidal category?

Comment: monoidal category implies that you have a way to assemble two objects $A$ and $B$ together in a new object $A\otimes B$. This is not the case usually in a groupoid, invertibility of morphisms does not let you compose the objects.

Answer (score 1):

A monoidal groupoid is just a [monoidal category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_category) that is also a [groupoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupoid).

In other words, it's a monoidal category where all morphisms are isomorphisms.